# How can I get the Send button event in Messages for my custom keyboard?

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

I am making a custom keyboard, and I'm working on auto-correct and auto-suggest features. One thing I'm looking for is how to tell when someone hit "Send" in Messages, for instance, so I can make a last correct before the text is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

First case and the simplest answer - just use `- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput` from your UIInputViewController subclass. But you'll catch it after send text. Details in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576834/1067147)

The second case - it just intercepts user tap on "Send" button on the extension view - it is just a button huh.

[image]

Comment: It seems you got collectionView working perfectly in your keyboard. I would appreciate any comment on my problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904906/collectionviewcells-iboutlet-is-nil-in-custom-keyboard-extension