# CollectionViewCell's IBoutlet is nil in Custom Keyboard Extension

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard

Well, it'd day 5, I have tried everything to make this work. Setup is simple 
I am trying to write a custom keyboard. 
Which is having the CollectionView, CollectionViewCell is powered by xib
I have one label, which would hold the emoji when running.

I did ready every single article here where IBOutlet is nil. 
Nothing is pointing to the direction that I haven't tried.

```
class CategoryCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var emojiLabel: UILabel!    

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
   }
```

Outlet is connected to the class. 
KeyboardViewController is CollectionViewData source and delegate.

I am able to write the same code and UIViewController is able to get the collectionView Cells and showing the emojis. 
I have run out of options. So I am posting here. 
There is nothing extraordinary that I am doing here. Except its a keyboard extension. 
Also, SIGQUIT is the biggest problem, any suggestions what is causing that. as I haven't able to put a finger on it.

Comment: How are you using the cell, have you set the nib with a class name of CategoryCollectionCell

Comment: @Scriptable : yes, its CategoryCollectionCell. and its registered, in viewdidlaod of keyboardViewController

Comment: In your `cellForItemAt ` function did you set the cell type to your Custom Class? `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionCell`

Comment: @Jake Yes, it does. as I mentioned I used the same code and create same for UIViewcontroller all is working fine.